# Change the value of a bool method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method wiche is `bool` and returns the value of `YES`. This method is declared in `BViewController`, is there a way when I access this method in `CViewController` and set the value of to `NO` ?

```
-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Something like that maybe ?

```
[self prefersNavigationBarHidden:NO ];
```

I know that I could do something like that :

```
 -(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden{
        return NO;
    }
```

But this method has to be triggered on a specific event

thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Why are you calling the method from C?

Comment: Why don't you use a property?

Comment: @Wain I have to change the value on a specific event and I have to call it in view controller C.

Comment: I'm not frustrated. But SO isn't a learning platform. You need an idea of properties. An explanation is included in *every* tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, your function is hard-coded and always returns `YES`. You will need to store the value somewhere, if you want to be able to change it, either from inside view controller B or from other places.

You can store it as a property instead:

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL prefersNavigationBarHidden;
```

And expose it on the .h file of view controller B. This way view controller C will have access to it, and will be able to change it.

Comment: hey thanks allot for your answer so I declared this property how can I now alter the value ?

Comment: Assuming view controller C has access to view controller B, you can access it like any other property, using dot notation. As a side note, like @Wain mentioned, I have to advise that it's not good practice to do these kind of stuff between two view controllers.

Comment: @Aviram  I think that the point of the question is that this dude does not now how to do that ...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context in which you want to use that method. If it's a method that you use to tell a view controller if it can display or not the navigation bar, one option is create a superclass, from which view controller C inherits, and define that method there. Then, override that method in your view controller C which should inherit from the superclass. Like this:

```
@interface MySuperclass : UIViewController
- (BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden;
@end

@implementation MySuperclass
-(BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden {
    return YES;
}

/*
  Use the value returned by the method to achieve what you want
  with that boolean value
*/
@end

//--------------------

@interface ViewControllerC : MySuperclass
@end

@implementation ViewControllerC
- (BOOL)prefersNavigationBarHidden {
    return NO; // return no for example
}
@end
```

It may not be your case, but it's for you to get an idea. As I told you, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.